# Php script for google firewall API

Tags: api

I am trying to do a simple script to change firewall rules on my VM hosting. I used the google API explorer, and the script generated is as follows

```
 curl --request PUT \  'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/learnstoresg/global/firewalls/intranet2?requestId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000033' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"TCP","ports":["4033","4016"]}],"sourceRanges":["101.127.7.227"]}' \
  --compressed
```

Anyone has an example of php script for google firewall or can help me convert this CURL statement into a php script?

Comment: Hi @user10322688, what is exactly the problem you're facing?

Comment: hi, sorry if it is a stupid question,

Comment: No, I'm not saying it's a stupid question, just try to explain what is the problem you're facing and what you've tried so far. :-)

Comment: I need help to convert this to php script with curl  - for example $resid = gen_resid();   // generate the resource Id 
$ch = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/learnstoresg/global/firewalls/intranet2?requestId=".$resid);

curl_setopt($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, $CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  - how do I get the headers above to be sent via curl

Comment: in other word, how do I get the headers to be sent together, using php

Comment: In other word, the syntax above works in google api explorer,  but i need it as a php script , any help much appreciated.